# Trouble saving phone numbers and addresses using 8base's GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, serverless

I just started building a project on 8base and am having a little trouble saving phone numbers and addresses. I chose the "smart" data type for both, though I keep getting validation errors whenever I try saving an address or phone number like so.

```
// Phone number
{
  phone: '+16178740945' 
}

// Address
{
  address: '8000 Main Street, New York, NYC 11210'
}
```

Anyone have any idea how this is supposed to work?

Comment: It may be helpful to edit your question to include the actual validation errors you are seeing.

Comment: Hey Daniel, it isn't giving me any specific errors other than `required keys missing`. I'm snooping around their API explorer a little harder, as I expect the answer should be in there.